What is the integral $\int_a^a f(x) dx$ if $f(x)$ is undefined at $a$?
For this question, I am assuming that infinite limits 'exist'. That is, a limit is considered not to exist if and only if the left and right-handed limits are different from each other. I am aware that the integral at a point of any function is considered to be $0$. At least, that is the answer the internet and AI give me. However, is there a rigorous sense in which the integral can be considered to be undefined as well? Here me out. Consider, for example, the function $\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$ for all $a < 0 < b$.  $\int_{a}^{0} \frac{1}{x} dx \to -\infty$ and $\int_{0}^{b} \frac{1}{x} dx \to +\infty$. So reasonably, as $a$ and $b$ approach $0$, either the integral remains undefined or approaches positive infinity (I am not sure which is more appropriate. On one hand,  approaching $0$ from the left or right gives different limits, on the other, I see a negative infinity being subtracted from a positive one.) The reason I think this question is important is because when solving integrals on functions like
$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x} & \text{if } x \le 0 \\
x + 1 & \text{if } 0 < x < 1 
\end{cases} $$
we consider the integral defined from $0$ to $1$. Because it only matters what happens to the right of the left-handed bound and to the left of the right-handed bound. That tells me that the more rigorous definition of the definite integral $$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{x \to b^-} F(x) - \lim_{x \to a^+} F(x)$$ where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative. So,  is my approach correct? Is there something I am missing? By the way, I am aware that the area under a curve at the point is $0$. What I am asking for is the definite integral.

If $f$ is not defined at $a$, then how and why do you want to integrate $f$ over ${a}$? By the way, when one writes $\int_a^b f$ and $f$ is not defined at $a$ or $b$ (or a finite amount of points), it is implicit that we really mean $\int_a^b g$ where $g = f$ whenever $f$ is defined and $g$ is otherwise arbitrary. This is because the value $g$ takes at a finite amount of points does not affect the value of $\int_a^b g$.

Because I am curious? We do things in maths not necessarily because we find them useful. Also, it plays into a question where I am asked to find values for which a specific definite integral is defined. Something like  $\int_0^a \frac{1}{x^3 + a} da$ And there exists a similar case to the one highlighted above. Edit: I have never seen that definition before. Interesting.

It cannot be $1/x$ for all $x\leq0.$ You have to give a value on at $0$ even if it is $+\infty$ or $-\infty.$

@ThomasAndrews Oh, my bad. But my point is that I am allowing the function to be undefined at x = $0$. Is there a better way to write that?

To answer this, let's go back to the formal definition of a Riemann integral.
To compute $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ for any $f(x)$; first of all we need $f(x)$ to be defined at every point $x$ with $a \leq x \leq b$.
Remember that formally, a function consists of a domain, a codomain, and a rule which assigns every element of the domain to a unique element of the codomain. So strictly speaking, your example $f$ has domain consisting of $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0,1)$. It cannot be integrated from $0$ to $1$, or from $0$ to $0$.
However, suppose that you've "filled in the holes" of $f$ however you may choose. If $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$, then we consider dividing $[a,b]$ into a bunch of subintervals: $a = x_0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \cdots \leq x_{n-1} \leq x_n = b$.
Then we choose any point $y_1$ we want between $x_0$ and $x_1$, another point $y_2$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$, etc.
We compute the Riemann Sum $\sum_{i=1}^n f(y_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$. This approximates the integral by taking rectangles whose base is each subinterval, and whose height is equal to the value of $f$ at some point in the subinterval.
If the Riemann Sums tend to a particular value as the lengths of the subintervals chosen tend to zero, we say the integral exists!

Now over the zero-length interval $[a,a]$, no matter how we divide the subintervals, they will all have length $0$: $a \leq x_0 \leq x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_n = a \implies x_0 = x_1 = \cdots = x_n = a$. And likewise all of the $y_i$'s will be $a$
So the Riemann Sums will always just be a sum of a bunch of $0$'s:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(y_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(a)(a-a) = \sum_{i=1}^n 0 = 0$$
Which means that $\int_a^a f(x)dx$ is always zero!!

What if you allow $f(a) = \pm \infty$? Well then, we have to figure out what $0$ times $\infty$ is. Here, the Riemann integral won't exactly work out for you, but using another kind of integral, the Lebesgue integral, we see that $\int_a^a +\infty = 0$. (Exactly how this occurs requires some measure theory.)

The last part is not true. The reason $\int_a^a +\infty = 0$ can be answered without any appeal to measure theory by defining $0\cdot\infty = 0$, and in fact, is also why it holds for the Lebesgue integral.
